# Configuring LDAP with jackrabbit for authentication

Tags: ldap, jackrabbit

I don't have much experience with [jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org) and LDAP. I am trying to authenticate the jcr users via LDAP.

Any source for how this works?

I have configured my `repository.xml` file like this :

```
<Security appName="Jackrabbit">
    <SecurityManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.DefaultSecurityManager"
        workspaceName="security">
    </SecurityManager>

    <AccessManager
        class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.DefaultAccessManager">
    </AccessManager>
    <LoginModule class="com.sun.security.auth.module.LdapLoginModule">
        <param name="userProvider" value="ldap://localhost:10389/o=sm" />
        <param name="authIdentity" value="uid={USERNAME}, ou=users, o=sm" />
        <param name="useSSL" value="false" />
        <param name="debug" value="true" />
    </LoginModule>
</Security>
```

When I run the application I am getting the following exception :

```
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Configured bean implementat
ion class com.sun.security.auth.module.LdapLoginModule was not found.
```

Any idea what is going wrong here ?

Comment: The first, obvious question: is the class available on the classpath (surely you've checked that first)?

Comment: Is this setup in OSGi? com.sun classes can generally be added via boot delegation.